# How to get network activity spinner status?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app in which if the data is loading, i want to make a button unclickable. If there is no network activity it means that since all data has been loaded, the button should then be clickable.

you can see the spinner here . top left.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke8Z2.png

How should the if statement look like if b.enabled = 0; is what makes the button unclickabl and making it 1 is clickable ?

what do I put in
    if (  )

Answer (score 1):

That spinner is *your* spinner. You cannot *not* know if it spinning, because you set it spinning. Thus, there is no point asking whether it is spinning; you already know. It is spinning if you have set it spinning, and it is not spinning (and is absent) if you have stopped it or have never set it spinning in the first place.

That spinner does *not* know anything whatever about whether "data is loading". Knowing that is up to *you*. It's just a spinner. It has no intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication]. isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible){
    //action if data is loading
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one you are looking for on the top left is:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
Of course use **YES** to show and **NO** to hide.

Then I would recommend using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for your request which has a success and failure block you can easily use to enable or disable your UI.

Example:

```
    //DISABLE YOUR UI INTERACTION HERE
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        //ENABLE YOUR UI INTERACTION ONCE REQUEST IS DONE AND SUCCESSFUL
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        //ENABLE YOUR UI INTERACTION ONCE REQUEST IS DONE BUT FAILED
    }];
```